# Let $G$ be a group of order 505.Is it cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group of order 505.Is it cyclic?

My try:By Sylow's theorem $G$ has a subgroup of order 101 and a subgroup of order 5.If both have been unique we could have concluded that $G$ is cyclic.

But here no. of Sylow 5 subgroup =$1+5k$ divides 101 which holds for $k=0 $ and $k=20$

How to proceed here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Sylow theorems, you know that the group of order 101 is unique.  Since that subgroup is unique, it is normal.  Therefore, $G$ has a normal subgroup of order 101 and a subgroup of order $5$ (which might not be normal).  If you continue with the Sylow theorems, you will find that the groups of this type are called semidirect products determined by maps from $\mathbb{Z}/5$ into Aut$(\mathbb{Z}/101)\simeq\mathbb{Z}/100$.  There is a map from $\mathbb{Z}/5$ into $\mathbb{Z}/100$, and this gives a noncyclic group of order 505.    In fact, the group can be presented as

$\langle x,y:x^5=1,y^{101}=1,xy=y^{36}x\rangle.$

Comment: can you please explain how are you getting such maps?

Comment: It's called the semidirect product.  Have you seen that product yet?

Comment: No I have learnt direct product of groups

Comment: It is much more complicated to explain the semidirect product.  I am trying to think of a way to answer this question, but the most natural explanations involve the semidirect product.

One thing that you can see is that when the subgroup $\mathbb{Z}/5$ is not normal, then the group cannot be cyclic.  However, one still must show that such a group exists.

Comment: it would be very nice of you if you can give some alternative solution

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $G$ is a group of order $pq (p<q)$ where $p$ and $q$ are prime and $p$ divides $q-1$ then there always exists a unique nonabelian group of order $pq$.Can you conclude now?

Proof of above result can be found here :[Non Abelian group of order pq](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1114735/non-abelian-group-of-order-pq)

Comment: I dont understand the proof at all

Comment: Do you know semi direct product?

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Michael Burr's answer, a number $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ is called a cyclicity-forcing  number if all groups of order $n$ are cyclic. There is a very nice characterization of these numbers, which can be found [here](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Classification_of_cyclicity-forcing_numbers). Since $n=105$ doesn't follow the criteria, there exists a non-cyclic group of order $105$.