# Construct a non-abelian group of order 203.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, automorphism-group

The question is from Herstein. Until now, semi direct product has not been covered in the material.
I am solving these type of questions using the procedure given by Herstein in previous sections.
I was able to solve it for order 55 but for order 203, I am facing an issue.
The procedure goes like this ::

Required Order = 203 = 29 * 7

Consider a cyclic group G of order 29.

G = $<a>$ such that $a^{29} = e$

And consider an automorphic mapping $\phi$: $a^i \to a^{6i}$. Ideally order of $\phi$ should be 7 here.
i.e. $\phi ^7 = I$.

But In this case, $\phi ^7 = a^{279936i} = a^{-i}$.

If $\phi ^7=I$ was true in this case, then next steps would be to consider a group containing all formal elements $x^ia^j$. This group is the required group asked for in the question which is of order 203.

where i = 0,1,2,3,4,5,6. and j = 0,1,2, ...... ,28.

And symbol x is subject to few conditions which are ::

$x^7=e$

$x^{-1}a^ix = a^{6i}$

$x^ia^j = x^ka^l$  iff i $\equiv$ k (mod 7) and j $\equiv$ l (mod 29).

Please let me know where I am going wrong, why $\phi^7$ isnot equal to I ?

Comment: It might be easier to look for the general case of order $pq$, see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1114735/non-abelian-group-of-order-pq).

Comment: I've no idea why you chose $a\mapsto a^6$. I think $a\mapsto a^5$ might work.

Comment: @ancientmathematician, It's based on the factorization of required group. Since 203 = 29*7, therefore the order of the automorphic mapping should be 7.
And for $a^5$, $\phi^7$ will be $a^{78125i}$, again it's not equal to $a^i$

Comment: Sorry, I made a slip, $a\mapsto a^5$ taken seven times inverts $a$ [as you say] so we need to square it. Try $a\mapsto a^{-4}$.

Comment: $a^{-4}$ will not work. But now that you have given me this hint of mapping it to a negative power. 
I was doing $a^i \to a^{6i}$. Instead if I do, $a^i \to a^{-6i}$, then $\phi^7$ = $a^{-279936i}$ = $a^{-279937i}*a^i$ = $a^{-(29*9653)i}*a^i$ = $e^{-1}*a^i$ = I.
Thus the order of $\phi$ is 7.
Thanks.

Comment: @quasi, how did you came up with list of $k$ ?

Comment: Correcting my earlier (deleted) comment, $a^k$ works for $k\in\{7,16,20,23,24,25\}$ or equivalently $k\in\{7,-13,-9,-6,-5,-4\}$. We want $k$ to be of order $7$ mod $29$, so if we find a primitive root $r$ (e.g., $r=2$), then the set of elements of order $7$ is the set $\{r^{4j}\;\text{mod}\;29:1\le j\le 6\}$.